# Graphene-Python: automatic schema generation from Django model

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I am trying to generate a Graphene schema from a Django model. I am trying to do this by iterating through the apps then the models and then adding the appropriate attributes to the generated schema.

This is the code:

```
registry = {}


def register(target_class):
    registry[target_class.__name__] = target_class


def c2u(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()


def s2p(name):
    s1 = re.sub("y$", "ie", name)
    return "{}s".format(s1)


class AutoSchemaMeta(type):

    def __new__(meta, clsname, superclasses, attributedict):
        new_class = type(clsname, superclasses, attributedict)
        for app_name in new_class.app_models.split(","):
            app_models = apps.get_app_config(app_name.strip()).get_models()
            for model in app_models:
                model_name = model._meta.model_name
                _model_name = c2u(model_name)

                if hasattr(new_class,_model_name):
                    continue
                _node_class = type("{}Node".format(model_name.title()),
                    (DjangoObjectType,),
                    {"Meta":{"model": model, "interfaces": (Node,), "filter_fields": []}})
                register(_node_class)
                setattr(new_class, "all_{}".format(s2p(_model_name)), DjangoFilterConnectionField(_node_class))
                setattr(new_class, _model_name, Node.Field(_node_class))
        print(new_class.__dict__)
        return new_class


class Query(metaclass=AutoSchemaMeta):

    app_models = "app1,app2"
```

When I run my application I get an exception:

> AssertionError: Found different types with the same name in the
>   schema: WorkflowNode, WorkflowNode.

Turns out there is a class already defined as WorkflowNode and I do not want to override it. So now I am stuck at finding out the classes that are already defined.

I am already excluding by attributes name with `if hasattr(new_class,_model_name): continue` but I would like to not rely on conventions and find out also all `Node`classes that have been defined elsewhere and if they exist use them instead of the one I am creating automatically

Comment: Edited as the initial problem was solved but I am still stuck

Comment: I ended up white listing the models I want generated like I do for the apps. Leaving the question open if anyone needs to do this too.

Comment: out of curiosity: why not graphene-django? Just for the sake of exercise?

Comment: Sorry fo the confusion, but this is graphene-jango. The problem is that for a django model like we have with hundreds of models you need to write boilerplate like this for each: `class User(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = graphene.List(User)

    def resolve_users(self, info):
        return UserModel.objects.all()
`

Comment: The code above lists all models that are in the apps listed in app_models. The code never went in production because of lack of time to test it and fix it. I still believe though that graphene should provide a schema through introspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the proposed solution but it doesn't work for a lot of reasons, including metaclass conflicts with graphene.ObjectType so I created a solution that works pretty well:

you would provide the subclassed ObjectType a list of your ORM models (in my case SQLAlchemy) and it auto creates the schema.  The only thing left to do would be to add special handling if you needed to add extra filtering options for any of the fields.

```py
class SQLAlchemyAutoSchemaFactory(graphene.ObjectType):

    @staticmethod
    def set_fields_and_attrs(klazz, node_model, field_dict):
        _name = camel_to_snake(node_model.__name__)
        field_dict[f'all_{(s2p(_name))}'] = FilteredConnectionField(node_model)
        field_dict[_name] = node_model.Field()
        # log.info(f'interface:{node_model.__name__}')
        setattr(klazz, _name, node_model.Field())
        setattr(klazz, "all_{}".format(s2p(_name)), FilteredConnectionField(node_model))

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass_with_meta__(
            cls,
            interfaces=(),
            models=(),
            excluded_models=(),
            default_resolver=None,
            _meta=None,
            **options
    ):
        if not _meta:
            _meta = ObjectTypeOptions(cls)

        fields = OrderedDict()

        for interface in interfaces:
            if issubclass(interface, SQLAlchemyInterface):
                SQLAlchemyAutoSchemaFactory.set_fields_and_attrs(cls, interface, fields)
        for model in excluded_models:
            if model in models:
                models = models[:models.index(model)] + models[models.index(model) + 1:]
        possible_types = ()
        for model in models:
            model_name = model.__name__
            _model_name = camel_to_snake(model.__name__)

            if hasattr(cls, _model_name):
                continue
            if hasattr(cls, "all_{}".format(s2p(_model_name))):
                continue
            for iface in interfaces:
                if issubclass(model, iface._meta.model):
                    model_interface = (iface,)
                    break
            else:
                model_interface = (CustomNode,)

            _node_class = type(model_name,
                               (SQLAlchemyObjectType,),
                               {"Meta": {"model": model, "interfaces": model_interface, "only_fields": []}})
            fields["all_{}".format(s2p(_model_name))] = FilteredConnectionField(_node_class)
            setattr(cls, "all_{}".format(s2p(_model_name)), FilteredConnectionField(_node_class))
            fields[_model_name] = CustomNode.Field(_node_class)
            setattr(cls, _model_name, CustomNode.Field(_node_class))
            possible_types += (_node_class,)
        if _meta.fields:
            _meta.fields.update(fields)
        else:
            _meta.fields = fields
        _meta.schema_types = possible_types

        super(SQLAlchemyAutoSchemaFactory, cls).__init_subclass_with_meta__(_meta=_meta, default_resolver=default_resolver, **options)

    @classmethod
    def resolve_with_filters(cls, info: ResolveInfo, model: Type[SQLAlchemyObjectType], **kwargs):
        query = model.get_query(info)
        for filter_name, filter_value in kwargs.items():
            model_filter_column = getattr(model._meta.model, filter_name, None)
            if not model_filter_column:
                continue
            if isinstance(filter_value, SQLAlchemyInputObjectType):
                filter_model = filter_value.sqla_model
                q = FilteredConnectionField.get_query(filter_model, info, sort=None, **kwargs)
                # noinspection PyArgumentList
                query = query.filter(model_filter_column == q.filter_by(**filter_value))
            else:
                query = query.filter(model_filter_column == filter_value)
        return query
```

and you create the Query like this:

```py
class Query(SQLAlchemyAutoSchemaFactory):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (Interface1, Interface2,)
        models = (*entities_for_iface1, *entities_for_iface2, *other_entities,)
        excluded_models = (base_model_for_iface1, base_model_for_iface2)
```

create an interface like this:

```py
class Interface1(SQLAlchemyInterface):
    class Meta:
        name = 'Iface1Node'
        model = Iface1Model
```

and SQLAlchemyInterface:

```py
class SQLAlchemyInterface(Node):
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass_with_meta__(
            cls,
            model=None,
            registry=None,
            only_fields=(),
            exclude_fields=(),
            connection_field_factory=default_connection_field_factory,
            _meta=None,
            **options
    ):
        _meta = SQLAlchemyInterfaceOptions(cls)
        _meta.name = f'{cls.__name__}Node'

        autoexclude_columns = exclude_autogenerated_sqla_columns(model=model)
        exclude_fields += autoexclude_columns

        assert is_mapped_class(model), (
            "You need to pass a valid SQLAlchemy Model in " '{}.Meta, received "{}".'
        ).format(cls.__name__, model)

        if not registry:
            registry = get_global_registry()

        assert isinstance(registry, Registry), (
            "The attribute registry in {} needs to be an instance of "
            'Registry, received "{}".'
        ).format(cls.__name__, registry)

        sqla_fields = yank_fields_from_attrs(
            construct_fields(
                model=model,
                registry=registry,
                only_fields=only_fields,
                exclude_fields=exclude_fields,
                connection_field_factory=connection_field_factory
            ),
            _as=Field
        )
        if not _meta:
            _meta = SQLAlchemyInterfaceOptions(cls)
        _meta.model = model
        _meta.registry = registry
        connection = Connection.create_type(
            "{}Connection".format(cls.__name__), node=cls)
        assert issubclass(connection, Connection), (
            "The connection must be a Connection. Received {}"
        ).format(connection.__name__)
        _meta.connection = connection
        if _meta.fields:
            _meta.fields.update(sqla_fields)
        else:
            _meta.fields = sqla_fields
        super(SQLAlchemyInterface, cls).__init_subclass_with_meta__(_meta=_meta, **options)

    @classmethod
    def Field(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # noqa: N802
        return NodeField(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def node_resolver(cls, only_type, root, info, id):
        return cls.get_node_from_global_id(info, id, only_type=only_type)

    @classmethod
    def get_node_from_global_id(cls, info, global_id, only_type=None):
        try:
            node: DeclarativeMeta = one_or_none(session=info.context.get('session'), model=cls._meta.model, id=global_id)
            return node
        except Exception:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def from_global_id(cls, global_id):
        return global_id

    @classmethod
    def to_global_id(cls, type, id):
        return id

    @classmethod
    def resolve_type(cls, instance, info):
        if isinstance(instance, graphene.ObjectType):
            return type(instance)
        graphene_model = get_global_registry().get_type_for_model(type(instance))
        if graphene_model:
            return graphene_model
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{instance} must be a SQLAlchemy model or graphene.ObjectType')
```